# Stata's predict uhat, residuals function in R

Tags: r, regression, stata, residuals, lm

I'm having trouble figuring out how to replicate Stata's command "predict uhat, residuals" in R for creating residuals.

Do I have to generate a normal sampling to accomplish this?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you describe what predict uhat, residuals does?

Comment: seems you just want to use residuals(), though your reference to normal sampling seems to indicate you are working with a specific (survey sampling?) model?

Comment: In Stata, `predict` can do different things depending on the previous model-fitting commands. But with the option `residuals` it is usually calculating plain residuals.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure about the "*Do I have to generate a normal sampling to accomplish this?*" but here are the parallel examples:

In Stata the `predict` command will not work unless you have done some analysis before that. For example, linear regression using `reg` command.

```
sysuse auto
reg price mpg
predict uhat, residual
```

This will give you the residual called uhat.

In R, same idea. You'll need to have an object first. After the `lm()` command, a set of residual will be saved in the model output. You'll need to use `$residual` to get it. Again here is an example in linear regression:

```
x    <- rnorm(1000)
y    <- x * 1.5 + rnorm(1000, 0, 250)
m01  <- lm(y ~ x)
uhat <- m01$residual
hist(uhat)
```

Comment: +1 Or `residuals(m01)`, which at least one advantage - it works with several model objects that don't come with a `$residuals` component already in them.